# Javascript: remove quotes from string of comma separated numbers

Tags: javascript

I have a string

```js
var s = "2,4,6,8,10"
```

I need output
`2,4,6,8,10`

Convert this string to int?
Is this at all possible?

Comment: What do you mean by output? `console.log(s)` will result in 2,4,6,8,10 being printed to the browser console. And no, that is not an int.

Comment: Ya I know that is not an int, but my api needs an input which should not be a string, so I either want to remove quotes.

Comment: @automation.ninja.08 That doesn't make sense. The quotes you have there are to tell the interpreter that it is a piece of text. They are not part of the actual string that is being stored. The number data type can only contain one single number, not a list. That is only possible with an array. So what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are looking for something like this.

1. split the string into substrings which each contain one number

```js
var arrayOfStrings = s.split(",");
```

2. convert these strings to numbers

```js
var arrayOfNumbers = arrayOfStrings.map(s => parseInt(s))
```

3. log the array of numbers

```js
console.log(...arrayOfNumbers)
```

combined

```js
var s = "2,4,6,8,10"
console.log(...s.split(",").map(item => parseInt(item)));
console.log("or")
console.log(s.split(",").map(item => parseInt(item)));
```

Answer (score 4):

You mean to turn a string of numbers to an array of numbers?  something like this:

```js
var s = "2,4,6,8,10";
var numberArray = s.split(',').map(i => +i);
console.log(numberArray);
```

Note: changed it to from `Number(i)` to `+i`, simpler and cleaner imo

Answer (score 3):

You can split the string by commas and then parseInt each string and get an array of numbers.

```js
let s = "2,4,6,8,10"

let splitted = s.split(',');
console.log(splitted);

let parsed = splitted.map(x => parseInt(x));
console.log(parsed);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can convert it into an array of numbers:

```js
let s = "2,4,6,8,10";
s = s.split(",");
s.forEach((i, index) => {
  s[index] = parseInt(i);
})

console.log(s)
```